# Passing args, kwargs in vim function

Tags: vimrc

What are the possible ways to pass a variable to a function in vim? Through trial-and-error, it seems like I can do:

```
:call LogOutput('asdf', 'WARNING')
```

But not:

```
:call LogOutput('asdf', level='WARNING')
```

Is the only way to pass an argument by its index? Is there anyways to specify what that argument is for it to be more readable?

Comment: You could pass a dictionary, and there is a varargs thing called a:000/...

Comment: `:h call()` also.

Answer (score 2):

A common trick is to use a dictionary. For example,

```
function! DoSomething(opts) abort
    let l:opts = extend(copy(a:opts), {'foo': 42, 'bar': 0, 'baz': -1}, 'keep')
    ...
endfunction

call DoSomething({'bar': 100})
```

But it's only good when the number of optional parameters is big. Otherwise, it's simpler just to stick to positional arguments:

```
function! DoAnotherThing(...) abort
    let l:foo = get(a:, 1, 42)
    let l:bar = get(a:, 2)
    let l:baz = get(a:, 3, -1)
    ...
endfunction

call DoAnotherThing(42, 100)
```